# Twitter Typeahead custom events aren't firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, twitter-typeahead

I'm working on a custom Angular.js directive to wrap [Twitter Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md). The typedown feature seems to work just fine, however none of the custom events seem to be firing at all. I'm using Angular 1.2.6, Twitter Typeahead 0.10.2 and jQuery 1.10.2. Here's a couple snippets of my code:

**search-doctors.html**

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="span11 input-append">
        <input type="search" class="span10" name="practiceName" ng-model="message.practiceName" required typedown="contactDoctors" />
        <span class="add-on search-glass"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**typedown.coffee**

```
angular.module('someApp')
  .directive('typedown', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      element.typeahead({
        name: attrs.typedown
        source: (query, cb) ->
          # Ultimately, this will call to a service that will return the array of
          # search results, but for simplicity's sake, I'm stubbing some dummy data.
          cb ['Neurocare of Scottsdale', 'Neurocare of Tempe']
      })
      # These never seem to get fired, despite following the instructions in
      # typeahead's documentation
      .on 'typeahead:opened', ->
        alert 'opened'
      .on 'typeahead:autocompleted typeahead:selected', (event, query) ->
        alert query
)
```

The typedown actually seems to be working on the UI. When I type 'neuro' into the search box, I get the expected behavior, but when I hit tab or click on an option to auto-complete, the corresponding event handlers do not fire. Also, when I begin typing, and the typedown opens up, the expected `typeahead:opened` event isn't firing.

I've tried binding the events to the element before calling `typeahead` on the directive's element. I've also tried using `bind` instead of `on` (though that shouldn't have any effect). Anyway, I'm running out of time and ideas to make this work. I'd love to get a quick sanity check and some extra eyes to see if there's something I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The guys from AngularUI already did a great job creating [a wrapper for typeahead for AngularJS](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead), I really recommend you to check it before diving into writing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While it looks great, I decided against using the Angular UI project, simply to limit the amount of third party dependencies I've got on this project (which are already fairly significant). Might be worth revisiting when I upgrade Bootstrap to 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a few days to work on other things, I circled back to me. It occurred to me that since I was already using **Bootstrap 2.3.2** that including **Twitter Typeahead** would likely cause conflicts with what script would be managing `$.fn.typeahead`. I managed to get it working by removing Twitter Typeahead and relying on the legacy implementation that's built into Bootstrap 2.3.2. I will be upgrading to Bootstrap 3 eventually, but that's a bit of a tall order right now, and the project will be used in hospitals, which are notoriously behind the curve in web tech.